# Auto-width image with `srcset` attribute

Tags: html, css, responsive-images

Say I have the following image:

```html
<img src="//picsum.photos/100" srcset="//picsum.photos/100 100w">
```

It appears that the `sizes` attribute I have not included defaults to `100vw`, hence the small image is upscaled to the width of the viewport.

What do I do if I don't want this behavior, but instead want the image to default to its intrinsic size?

I would expect that this image would default to 100px in width on a normal display, and 50px on a 2x (retina) display.

If I specify my own `sizes` attribute of `100px`, this doesn't solve the problem of displaying it at `50px` when on a retina display.

The reason I need this behavior is because in my system users are allowed to upload images of any size and place them on a page, and I am generating an `srcset` with multiple steps up to the max size of their image, and I need a way for the image to display at the correct width given the size of the image and the pixel density of the user's screen.

Can this behavior for auto-width images be achieved using `srcset`?

In my research I've found [this article](https://medium.com/@MRWwebDesign/responsive-images-the-sizes-attribute-and-unexpected-image-sizes-882a2eadb6db) which addresses the issue directly. The author recommends adding the `width` attribute with the maximum size of the image to revert what the `sizes` attribute does to the image's intrinsic size. However, he does not address how to make this work with differing pixel densities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems there isn't a way to have an image with `srcset` default to its natural size, taking DPR into account. The `sizes` attribute, which defaults to `100vw` if not set on an image with `srcset`, redefines the image's intrinsic width, and there doesn't seem to be a way to reset it without providing an explicit width yourself.

In my specific situation I discovered that we were already storing the user's DPR in a cookie, so server-side I've started setting the `width` attribute on images to the max width of the image divided by the user's DPR. This prevents the image from being displayed larger than the original size, and ensures that the image is sized appropriately for devices with high pixel densities.

Of course, you'll probably want to combine this with `max-width: 100%;` in your CSS to prevent the image from displaying larger than its container.

Example solution:

```html
<!-- Width generated server-side for standard displays: -->
<img src="//picsum.photos/100" srcset="//picsum.photos/100 100w" width=100>

<!-- Width generated server-side for displays with a DPR of 2: -->
<img src="//picsum.photos/100" srcset="//picsum.photos/100 100w" width=50>
```